# Media query does not work for Ipad

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

I am new with using media queries.
I am working on a website which I want it to be correctly displayed on Ipad.

```
I have tried this,

//css use for Ipad

   @media only screen 
    and (min-device-width : 768px) 
     and (max-device-width : 1024px) {
      .overlayBox{
            width:200px;
         }
  }


// css use for Window
    .overlayBox{
         width:450px;
  }
```

But i am having problem that media queries doesn't work for Ipad. It takes window css.
Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Have you added this? `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`

Comment: Tablet portrait : @media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 999px)

Comment: @NathanLee: i try but not work.

Comment: @DarkBee:Want to use on Portrait and landscape.

Comment: We usualy let the landscape tablet view scale to the default screen layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `device-width` and `device-height` to target specific  devices, then use `orientation` to target portrait or landscape.

```
@media only screen and (device-width: 768px) and (device-height: 1024px) and (orientation: portrait) {
    .myrules { 
        width: 200px;
    }
}
```